# popup postion while screen resize horizontaly 

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have Link in horizontal top menu to open popup. The link is an image about 150px. Then have a popup div it has absolution position to right align with menu image. Now the problem arise when the screen is re size horizontal it lose the alignment with button and it goes misplace.

how I can change the position of popup with menu image to keep it align

The site build in wordpress using firebird theme. I have try to place it in relative position but not succeeded.

popup css,

```
    .quote {
    background:url('images/form-bg.png') no-repeat;width:400px !important;height:510px  !important;
    z-index:999999;position:absolute;top:77px;left:550px; padding-left:30px;padding-top:39px;display:none; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get the offset top of menu image and set this top property to popup top 
like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#menu image').click(function(){
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  //this will represent you click menu image  
     $('#popup').css({'top':offset.top});
  });
});
```